# Flutter code preview on mobile device from online source

Tags: flutter, mobile, app-preview

I'm just trying to achieve a code review on a device without having to install the app.
There have been other systems like Apache Cordova which have done this in the past. You will code something on one machine or online and then you can download an app from the app store and then connect via a QR code. Finally, you will be able to view that code on your device as if the app was installed on your device.

Using Flutter, is there anything similar that can be achieved without the code being installed on the device? Even better if this could be achieved through some kind of link that would open a PWA full-screen app etc.

What is the best way to approach this?